# Error in align environment with equation using union and intersection of sets

Tags: equations, formatting

I try with the align environment without success to get the following equation:
[image: LaTeX]

Can anyone help me? Here is my code but I get all the time the error message `"Extra }, or forgotten \right"`

```
\begin{align}\label{eq18}
  &\left\{N_{A_{1},1} = n_{1},\hdots,N_{A_{1},m}=n_{m} \right\} =  \\
  &\left\{\cup_{b_{1} \in A_{1}(1)} \cup_{a_{2} \in A_{2}(2)} \cdots &\cup_{b_{m} \in A_{1}(m)} \cup_{a_{m+1} \in A_{2}(m+1)}  \nonumber \\
  &\left\{\cap_{i=1}^{m}\left\{N_{A_{1}(i)} = n_{1},X_{K_{i}} = b_{i}, X_{K_{i}+1} = a_{i+1} \right\} \right\} \right\} \cup \nonumber \\
  &\left\{ \cup_{b_{1} \in A_{1}(1)} \cup_{a_{2} \in A_{2}(2)} \cdots &\cup_{a_{m} \in A_{2}(m)} \cup_{b_{m} \in A_{1}(m)}  \nonumber \\
  &\left\{ &\cap_{i=1}^{m-1} \left\{N_{A_{1}(i)} = n_{1},X_{K_{i}} = b_{i}, X_{K_{i}+1} = a_{i+1} \right\}  \cap \nonumber \\
  &\left\{N_{A_{1}(m)} = n_{m}, X_{K_{m}} = b_{m}, X_{K_{m} + 1} = \omega \right\} \right\} \right\}.
\end{align}
```

Comment: For one, `\left{` should be `\left\{`

Comment: Also, `\left...\right` cannot be broken across multiple lines.  Use `\biggl...\biggr` as an alternative, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a start...

As noted in my comments,

1. For one, `\left{` should be `\left\{`.  Likewise for `\right}`.  However, for this solution, even those won't work...see #2.
2. `\left...\right` cannot be broken across multiple lines. Use `\biggl...\biggr` as an alternative, for example.
3. Your use of line breaks `\\` and column separators `&` needs refinement.

The MWE.  Suggest you format your source code more legibly, using `&` and `\\` as natural break points.  It makes debugging easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq18} \{N_{A_{1},1} = n_{1},\hdots&
  ,N_{A_{1},m}=n_{m} \} = \\ 
&\biggl\{\cup_{b_{1} \in A_{1}(1)} \cup_{a_{2} \in A_{2}(2)} \cdots 
  \cup_{b_{m} \in A_{1}(m)} \cup_{a_{m+1} \in A_{2}(m+1)} \nonumber \\ 
&\biggl\{\cap_{i=1}^{m}\biggl\{N_{A_{1}(i)} = n_{1},X_{K_{i}} = b_{i},
  X_{K_{i}+1} = a_{i+1} \biggr\} \biggr\} \biggr\} \cup \nonumber \\ 
&\biggl\{ \cup_{b_{1} \in A_{1}(1)} \cup_{a_{2} \in A_{2}(2)} \cdots
  \cup_{a_{m} \in A_{2}(m)} \cup_{b_{m} \in A_{1}(m)} \nonumber \\
& \biggl\{ \cap_{i=1}^{m-1} \biggl\{N_{A_{1}(i)} = n_{1},X_{K_{i}} = 
  b_{i}, X_{K_{i}+1} = a_{i+1} \biggr\} \cap \nonumber \\ 
&\biggl\{N_{A_{1}(m)} = n_{m}, X_{K_{m}} = b_{m}, X_{K_{m} + 1} = 
  \omega \biggr\} \biggr\} \biggr\}. 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the equation at the top has different sizes of the symbol {

Comment: @wayne Symbol size, using this approach, is determined by (in order of growing size), `\{`, `\bigl\{`, `\Bigl\{`, `\biggl\{`, and `\Biggl\{`.  Choose the desired size.  I have edited the result.